# MySQL QUERY condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I try make search for my site. Example: have field name = city, if city is empty my query looks: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = ALL;`

I don't know how to write: `CITY = ALL` correct, expression `CITY is not null` will be complicated because I should be remove `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE @SearchParam IS NULL OR City = @SearchParam
```

If his parameter `@SearchParam` is passed to the query with a `NULL` value then it will return all the data in the table, otherwise it will search for the cities with this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `where` completely

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = @searchstring or @searchstring is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about very optimized queries, you can use a like operator compare with

```
City like '%@exp'
```

If exp is empty the query returns all Cities.

I personally do not recommend this :)

All the best

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting them all, why have the `WHERE` clause in at all?

`SELECT * FROM TABLE`

Note, you should avoid using `SELECT *` whenever possible. As it is a waste of resources, always be explicit with your columns returned.

Comment: because are other field which are not null

Comment: Then don't include `city` in your `WHERE` clause?  Your question is very ambigious in what you actually have, and what you actually want.

Comment: have many field (search cryteriuos) if one of cryteriaus field is empty must be example: `where city all and lang = something and something = something1;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (CITY = SOMETHING) OR (SOMETHING is null);
```